# Attribute "layout_anchorGravity" already defined with incompatible format

Tags: android, ionic-framework, crosswalk

when I try to build my Ionic project for Android with [Crosswalk](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview/issues) I get following error. Without Crosswalk everything works fine..

> platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/armv7/debug/values/values.xml:243:
>   AAPT: Attribute "layout_anchorGravity" already defined with
>   incompatible format.

and

> What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':processArmv7DebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

- Ionic CLI: 3.17.0
- cordova-android: 6.3.0
- Crosswalk: 2.4.0

Has someone a hint or a solution for me? 
Thanks in advance <3

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed @frede?

Comment: Got any solution ?

Comment: hey guys, sry for the late response. yes, i did fix it, but actually I'm not sure how D: Several updates to Ionic, the android sdk, cordova-android and some plugins I've been using probably did the job. Nothing fancy I guess. Working with Ionic sometimes is a pain in the arse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `com.android.support:*-v7:27.1.x` gradle dependencies, change it to `com.android.support:*-v7:26.1.0` or lower version. Here is the link of [Recent Support Library Revisions](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions)

Answer (score 0):

It happen when you make update build sdk version ,I resolved it by Searching layout_anchorGravity inside entire project in Android Studio ,using CTR+H shortcut,
it open file /users/{user}/.android/build.cache/~/output/res/values/values.xml
I delete this line from  file

```
<declare-styleable name="CoordinatorLayout_LayoutParams"><attr name="android:layout_gravity"/><attr format="string" name="layout_behavior"/><attr format="reference" name="layout_anchor"/><attr format="integer" name="layout_keyline"/><attr name="layout_anchorGravity"><flag name="top" value="0x30"/><flag name="bottom" value="0x50"/><flag name="left" value="0x03"/><flag name="right" value="0x05"/><flag name="center_vertical" value="0x10"/><flag name="fill_vertical" value="0x70"/><flag name="center_horizontal" value="0x01"/><flag name="fill_horizontal" value="0x07"/><flag name="center" value="0x11"/><flag name="fill" value="0x77"/><flag name="clip_vertical" value="0x80"/><flag name="clip_horizontal" value="0x08"/><flag name="start" value="0x00800003"/><flag name="end" value="0x00800005"/></attr></declare-styleable>
```

and then from onther java file I removed import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;

I clean and build ,it build successfully